# qt registerresource from raw data

Tags: c++, qt

I am just starting to learn about  the `QResource`. As I understand it, it is just a way to create a "directory/File" structure in memory.

I'd like my application to create a resource (at run time) from a raw data. E.g. my application could create a image resulting from some computation and would want to save it as a resource for further usage.

I thought that the constructor:

```
QResource::registerResource( const uchar * rccData, const QString & mapRoot = QString()
```

was meant to do that, but I probably missed something as I expected a `size` argument...

what is rccData then?

How big the the created resource?

How can I create a resource from raw data?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: With QResource::registerResource you are only able to load a valid .qrc file. This file will be created by the Qt resource compiler. This enables the user to store resources outside of the main executable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QResource` gives you access to data stored in resource files `.qrc`. These files inherit a directorylike structure, which then can be accessed through the QResource class. These files can be compiled into the application or can be loaded at runtime via `QResource::QResource ( const QString & file = QString(), const QLocale & locale = QLocale() )` consructutor. Those loaded files then virtually repesent a directory structure in memory, but `QResource` is not meant to create a directory structure out of nothing.

Comment: So Qressource gives you the possibility to load files in memory, but no way to add any file directly in memory (without using the OS filesystem)? what does the rccData in the above function points to?  /thanks

Comment: rccData points to a .rcc-file loaded into memory, as ``registerResource(QString,QString)`` reads the given file from disk and loads it. At least thats what i read from the docs. These files are created with the RCC Tool using the -binary switch.